# From the terminal, how can I disable iTunes from running when a device is connected?

Tags: itunes, terminal

Using terminal, I want to disable the feature of iTunes that causes it to run whenever a device is plugged in, but I want to do this entirely from the terminal, so that it can be part of an OSX setup script.

Comment: Woops! I accidentally clicked the button. This did not solve my problem!

Comment: which answer didn't solve your problem. The accepted one will prevent the initial setup dialog, mine will kill iTunes from auto-launching permanently; however, that app is inside the iTunes app itself, so you'll need to dig for it - /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app I'm no Terminal guru so idk how you would disable it from in there

Comment: `sudo rm -r /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app` worked, but I had to reboot after. Thanks @Tetsujin!

Comment: Welcome - I'm actually voting to reopen this as the Terminal requirement separates it from the linked question.

Comment: @Tetsujin If you want to respond with the answer, I'll accept it. There's likely a way to unload a plist with launchd, too.

Comment: A device (probably) isn't connecting from terminal. The question would be more clear if it was entitled, "From the terminal, how can I disable iTunes from running when a device is connected".

Comment: I'm not sure I'm confident enough in Terminal to want to grab the 15 points - if someone with better chops wants to drop in a definitive answer, i'd be happier to see that than I would a few points.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to run this command in terminal, then restart iTunes:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunesHelper ignore-devices 1
```